# How to create new users with JWT Auth Plugin?

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to build an application using ReactJS and Wordpress Rest Api. I'm using JWT Auth Plugin and it works great but if I try to create a new user without being logged I get this error below:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "statusCode": 403,
  "code": "jwt_auth_no_auth_header",
  "message": "Authorization header not found.",
  "data": []
}
```

I understand that I need a token to make POST requests but if it's a new user that is trying to register on my application, how can I generate a token for a user that doesn't exist yet?

Here is the code of my user_post.php:

```
<?php 

function api_user_post($request){

    $email = sanitize_email($request['email']);
    $senha = $request['senha'];
    $nome = sanitize_text_field($request['nome']);
    $user_exists = username_exists($email);
    $email_exists = email_exists($email);


    if(!$user_exists && !$email_exists && $email && $senha) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user($email, $senha, $email);
        
        $response = array(
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'display_name' => $nome,
            'first_name' => $nome,
            'role' =>  'professor'
        );

        wp_update_user($response);   
        

    }else{
        $response = new WP_Error('email', 'Email já cadastrado.', array('status' => 403) );
    }
    return rest_ensure_response($response);
}

function resgister_api_user_post(){
    register_rest_route('api', '/usuario', array(
        array(
            'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback' => 'api_user_post',
        ),
    ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'resgister_api_user_post');

?>
```

Comment: the REST API has no endpoints for user registration out of the box, you would need to ask the JWT plugin authors if they implement one though they might not.

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply!! I found on plugin's documentation a hook for create a whitelist for some endpoints and this solved the 'problem'

Comment: bro have you figured this out? Would you mind sharing what you did?

Comment: Basicaly what i did was to create a whitelist for the endpoints that has no need of generate a token. In the documentation of JWT plugin they show some hooks for this.

__code:__

`add_filter( 'jwt_auth_whitelist', function ( $endpoints ) {
    $your_endpoints = array(
        '/wp-json/api/usuario/',
        '/wp-json/api/password/lost',
    );

    return array_unique( array_merge( $endpoints, $your_endpoints ) );
} );`